# Compare two nested objects by its keys and get the matched object/array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I have 2 objects a and diff
I need the matching array or object from nested object "a".

The INPUT as below :

```
 var a = {
"AMI_DESCRIPTION":{
    "tags":{
        "aws":1,
        "vendor_param":1
    }
},
"AMI_ID":{
    "description":"The AWS AMI id for the version of Ontap for the VSA to boot up with",
    "tags":{
        "aws":1,
        "vendor_param":1
    }
},
"AMI_TYPE":{
    "allow":[
        "byol",
        "paygo10",
        "paygo2",
        "paygo"
    ],
    "default":"byol",
    "description":"Defined the type of Cloud Ontap AMI to be deployed",
    "tags":{
        "aws":1,
        "vendor_param":1
    }
},
"AWSCLI_PATH":{
    "default":"/usr/software/bin/aws",
    "description":"Path to AWS CLI binaries",
    "tags":{
        "aws":1,
        "dev_only":1,
        "vendor_param":1
    }
},
"AWS_DISABLE_ROLLBACK":{
    "allow":[
        "true",
        "false"
    ],
    "default":"false",
    "description":"",
    "tags":{
        "aws":1,
        "dev_only":1,
        "unsupported":1,
        "vendor_param":1
    }
},
"IMAGE_BUILDNAME":{
        "allow":[
            "cst-ok",
            "cit-ok",
            "none",
            "ignore_filter"
        ],
        "default":"cit-ok",
        "description":"filter",
        "tags":{
            "aws":1,
            "gcp":1,
            "vendor_param":1
        }
},
"IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE":{
        "description":"tedst",
        "tags":{
            "common":1,
            "vendor_param":1
        }
},
```

Map the `a` object and return the values of fields present in the `diff` object

```
 var diff = {
    "IMAGE_BUILDNAME":"testing",
    "IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE":"no"
```

}

Expected Output:

```
  "IMAGE_BUILDNAME":{ "description":"sdsd.", "tags":{ "aws":1, "gcp":1, 
  "vendor_param":1 } }, "IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE":{ "allow":[ "debug", "non-debug", 
  "ignore_filter" ], "default":"non-debug", "description":"filter.", "tags":{                
   "aws":1, "gcp":1, "vendor_param":1 } }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: I've edited the output so YOU CAN READ IT - please provide the logic to go from input to output

Comment: and you go and undo it all - well done

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry for undoing it. i did not checked that

Comment: for example, why is `"description": "sdsd."` - where does that come from? how is `"allow": ["debug", "non-debug", "ignore_filter"]` in the output? why is `debug` in that array? similarly for other property in the output, there is no logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `diff` properties and add each property of `diff` to `output` as field and its value from the `a` object :

```
 var output = {};

    for (let p in diff) {
        output[p]=a[p]
    }
```

**Full example**

```js
var a = {
    "AMI_DESCRIPTION": {
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "AMI_ID": {
      "description": "The AWS AMI id for the version of Ontap for the VSA to boot up with",
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "AMI_TYPE": {
      "allow": [
        "byol",
        "paygo10",
        "paygo2",
        "paygo"
      ],
      "default": "byol",
      "description": "Defined the type of Cloud Ontap AMI to be deployed",
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "AWSCLI_PATH": {
      "default": "/usr/software/bin/aws",
      "description": "Path to AWS CLI binaries",
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "dev_only": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "AWS_DISABLE_ROLLBACK": {
      "allow": [
        "true",
        "false"
      ],
      "default": "false",
      "description": "",
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "dev_only": 1,
        "unsupported": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "IMAGE_BUILDNAME": {
      "allow": [
        "cst-ok",
        "cit-ok",
        "none",
        "ignore_filter"
      ],
      "default": "cit-ok",
      "description": "filter",
      "tags": {
        "aws": 1,
        "gcp": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    },
    "IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE": {
      "description": "tedst",
      "tags": {
        "common": 1,
        "vendor_param": 1
      }
    }
    }

    var diff = {
      "IMAGE_BUILDNAME": "testing",
      "IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE": "no"
    }


    var output = {};

    for (let p in diff) {
        output[p]=a[p]
    }
    
    console.log(output)
```